# How to get the id of a window.alert()?

Tags: javascript

I want to pop up a window.alert() if the user mouses out of an area when they haven't saved changes yet (for structural reasons, there are several forms and a common problem I've seen in other apps is making changes in multiple areas, submitting one and losing the rest) and automatically close the alert when they mouse back into the area.  To do that, I need the id of the window that pops up, but I'm not sure how to get it.

Comment: Alerts are not DOM elements, they don't have an ID.

Comment: Use a CSS dialog instead of `window.alert()` if you want more control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No `alert()` please :)

*Actually* an `alert()` will block further code execution anyway so even if you COULD close it programatically it would never actually execute that dialog-closing code.

You need something you can access through the DOM (like every other response here says).

Make your Javascript track the mouse location and upon leaving the area you overlay a dark translucent background or do a modal dialog

### [Techniques on creating modal dialogs](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/)

**I would also advise** adding a `pointer-events: none;` and `position: fixed` to the underlying content to prevent further action until the user actually goes back where they should be.

If you want real specifics on how to code this let me know.  I'm hoping you'll travel down the rabbit hole and discover the wonders on your own, though.  **Much more satisfying.**

Answer (score 2):

The window does not have an id, and you cannot close it from Javascript. It is not a part of the DOM.

You can only open an `alert()` box, and then wait till the user closes it. Nothing else.